# JavaScript 2 onclick Events but just do the first

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript functions which get run 2 times when I click on one element. Take a look at my code, I only want that the first call will be done not the second also:

```
<p class="chat" onclick="Open('chat')">
 <img class="chatpicture" src="jpg/1.jpg" onclick="Open('user')">
</p>
```

When I click on the image then also the p element with his onclick function will be run. Because the image onclick is inside the p element which also have onclick.

What is the best way to only let the image onclick run and not at same time also run the p element onclick?

Comment: I strongly recommend [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66504350/295783) instead of cancelling events

Comment: why do you dont like cancel event in this case i think its most easy solution?

Comment: Because it is a hack that is addressing a problem of nested elements with inline event handlers. If you had not decided to have multiple event handlers on nested elements, then there had not been a problem. In my solution I SPECIFICALLY handle your two events separately and you can extend to other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

> The `stopPropagation()` method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring; for instance, clicks on links are still processed. If you want to stop those behaviors, see the [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method.

**Demo:**

```js
function Open(inputVal){
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(inputVal);
}
```

```html
<p class="chat" onclick="Open('chat')">
  <img class="chatpicture" src="jpg/1.jpg" onclick="Open('user')">
</p>
```

Comment: @mplungjan works also of course, i could also use if(event.target.className=="chatpicture")return; but i was looking for this other things to just stop the second call in this case

Answer (score 1):

Delegate and test the class

```js
const Open = str => console.log(str);
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("chat")) Open('chat');
  else if (tgt.classList.contains("chatpicture")) Open('user');
})
```

```css
img { height:50px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="chat">
    Start chat
    <img alt"User details" class="chatpicture" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/managers-15/494/Untitled-32-512.png">
  </p>
  <p class="chat">
    Start chat
    <img alt"User details" class="chatpicture" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/managers-15/494/Untitled-32-512.png">
  </p>
  <p class="chat">
    Start chat
    <img alt"User details" class="chatpicture" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/managers-15/494/Untitled-32-512.png">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: works also of course, you can also do this if(event.target.className=="chatpicture")return; but i was looking for just stop the second functions call in this case

Comment: And does not need to cancel events. Just handles the events specifically to the element you click